# C/C++ Debugger does not work in VSC despite correct config

Tags: c++, c, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

If I try to run a debugging session on Visual Studio Code with C++ I get this error[image: Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid]

> Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid
>
> Open 'launch.json'

This is my config, I want the debugging session to launch in the VSC terminal using WSL.

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb", //here :(
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
      

    ]
}
```

G++ and GDB are both installed [locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBSzM.png) and [WSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWCSs.png).I tried using all these directories for the "miDebuggerPath" path; did not work.

Comment: Are you in a [remote folder or workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_open-a-remote-folder-or-workspace)?

Comment: In the screenshot im in a workspace, I also tried hopping on WSL remotely, but it tells me that the debug type "cppdbg" is not recognized and tells me to install an extension for it. When I click install it takes me to the extensions list with "cppdbg" as a search term but nothing is found https://imgur.com/a/p9oA487

Comment: Please put the error message into the question, so that the next one is able to find it here. Also, try searching for it to begin with. Images of text are generally bad and frowned upon. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I got this because I installed MSYS2 (which doesn't have a debugger by default?) instead of MinGW (which does)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the miDebuggerPath to the path where gdb is installed in your WSL-environment.

So you have to set miDebuggerPath to:

```
"miDebuggerPath": "/usr/share/gdb",
```

when you wanto to run gd in a WSL-Environment. Change it to

```
"miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
```

when you want to debug in Windows.

Comment: I already did that and posted it as a screenshot in the post.

Comment: Fixed, just give it another try.

Comment: same error as before

Comment: Are you running VS-Code in the WSL-Environment? If not you have to use the Windows path c:/mingw/bin/gdb++

Comment: If I do that it gives me a formatting error, and the debugger doesn't even run.

Comment: Right, just check the post again, I have updated the paths. Hope that helps

Comment: I get an error in the terminal, and then I get a popup. https://imgur.com/a/XpRuRbv

Answer (score 0):

Install C/C++ extension on WSL Remote Subsystem even if you have it locally installed.

Comment: Op already mentioned he installed gdb in both WSL and Windows